# UEFI Stub booting not working

Tags: boot, uefi

I am trying to boot Arch Linux via an EFI Stub. I created an EFI partition (formatted as FAT32), a swap partition and a main partition on which I installed the Arch Linux core package group. I then used the efibootmgr to configure my motherboard to use the EFI partition to boot using the command as follows:

```
# efibootmgr --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 1 --create --label "mysystem" --loader /vmlinuz-linux --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX rw initrd=\initramfs-linux.img' --verbose
```

I know that this worked because the boot option "mysystem" is showing up in my motherboard's BIOS boot options and it lists the SSD involved so I know the PARTUUID I used is correct.

However, when I tell the machine to boot this way it pauses briefly and then fails (either going back to the BIOS setup or giving an error message depending on how it was initiated).

So, either the EFI partition is empty for some reason or the files there are not matching the settings in the efibootmgr instruction. But I do not know how to diagnose this further. How do I even find out the contents of the EFI partition in the first place?

Comment: Paste the output of `efibootmgr` and `tree $esp` (for your ESP, obviously).

Comment: @jasonwryan That is not easy to do because the system is not booting, so I do not have web access for it yet. The command "tree $esp" results in the error "zsh: command not found: tree".

Comment: You chroot in from the live media and paste from there. Instead of tree you can use `ls -R`.

Comment: @jasonwryan ls -R $esp results in showing a single file: install.txt which is the file in the root directory of the archiso ramdisk.

Comment: *You chroot in* from the archiso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

use: `UUID istead` of `PRTUUID`

```
root=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: As a clarification: the Linux kernel/initramfs/tools will usually prefer the **filesystem** UUID, but the UEFI firmware wants the **partition** UUID.